# Is there a bounded lock-free blocking queue?

Tags: java, concurrency

Currently we have LinkedBlockingQueue and ConcurrentLinkedQueue.

LinkedBlockingQueue can be bounded, but it uses locks.

ConcurrentLinkedQueue doesn't use locks, but it is not bounded. And it is doesn't block which makes it hard to poll.

Obviously I can't have a queue that both blocks and is lock-free (wait-free or non-blocking or something else). I don't ask for academical definitions.

Does anyone know a queue implementation that is mostly lock-free (doesn't use a lock in the hot path), blocks when empty (no need to busy waiting), and is bounded (blocking when full)? Off-heap solution is welcome as well.

I heard about LMAX Disruptor, but it doesn't look like a queue at all.

I am happy to know non-general solutions too (Single-Producer-Single-Consumer, SPMC, MPSC)

If there are no known implementations, I am also happy to know possible algorithms.

Comment: It might make this question more "non-closable" if you described your problem domain. Now you're just asking for an outside resource.

Comment: JDK doesn't provide a queue implementation that, (1) is mostly lock-free, (2) doesn't require busy waiting, and (3) bounded. LinkedBlockingQueue and ArrayBlockingQueue meet (2) and (3), ConcurrentLinkedQueue only meets (1). And what I want is a queue that meets all of them. If an implementation is not available, an algorithm description is also welcome. According to LMAX, disruptor ring buffer seems to meet all, but it doesn't look like a queue, and I believe the underlying algorithm may be hard to implement a queue.

Comment: I meant to explain a bit about what kind of domain you're working with. The requirements for a performant queue were clear in your question. As for LMAX disruptor, you'd need to incorporate it to your architecture in a broader way. It's not a drop-in replacement for a `Queue` after all.

Comment: I am working on a message processing system. I am exploring ways to improve the system. But even without this work, I was curious about queue implementation techniques. I was curious long ago, why Java doesn't implement a "better" bounded blocking queue. I want to know if there are "better" algorithms (not necessarily as generic purpose as current ones).

Comment: If you were curious about why Java doesn't implement a "better" bounded blocking queue, then surely you know of a "better" bounded blocking queue? Or are you just assuming a lot of things? A lot of work went into `java.util.concurrent` at 1.5 and later, so I'm not sure why you'd assume they somehow slacked off and didn't implement something that seems so obvious to you.

Comment: @Kayaman "Better" is vague, and I don't mean better in every way. I searched a little, and found some specific algorithms. Surely some of them are useful to someone. Not necessarily me, but someone else who comes to this page. Before Disruptor is written, we already have java.util.concurrent. And at least some of us agree it is better then java.util.concurrent in some aspects. So I know a "better" queue, namely disruptor. If someone is helpful and tell something I don't know, maybe I get enthusiast and decide to make the engineering effort to make something as useful as disruptor.

Comment: Your whole question is vague, and seems to assume a lot of things that simply aren't true. You're comparing apples to oranges, and drawing wrong conclusions. If you want to see high-speed collections, look at [OpenHFT](https://github.com/OpenHFT). Your approach of "maybe I get enthusiastic" is a far cry from actually creating something useful.

Comment: OK, then vote to close it if you can.

Comment: I did, long ago. That's why I was asking further questions. I thought there was a real question hiding under, but it seems that there wasn't.

Comment: Seems you don't understand the exploration vs exploitation dilemma.

Comment: Well, your question is still bad and I'm fairly sure that this little escapade of yours won't result in anything concrete. However if you do manage to create something useful, do share.

Comment: I am asking a very specific question. Namely a queue with certain liveness properties. It is just like, is it possible to ask, is it possible to sort a list in O(n), or is there a library that can sort a list in O(n) and is easy to use. Did I say there MUST be ONE? If you know there is one, then this question is not useless, because we know we can do something. If you know it is not possible (namely self-contradictory), then prove it, and this question is not useless, because now we know we can't do something.

Comment: You're asking for an outside resource, which is one of the basis for closing a question (in case you can't see, there are 3 close votes at the moment). You're also making it pretty damn impossible to answer this question in a negative way, since "no, there's no such a queue" would be quite a bold statement. Can't you just accept that you've asked a bad question and move on? If I were in your position I'd be scouring the web instead of going one-on-one on SO. Note: you could ask "is it possible to sort in O(n)", but asking for a library to do that would be off-topic.

Comment: Of course there is possible way to negate this answer. I know there is no algorithm to sort a list in less than O(n). You seems to know little.

Comment: You seem to be confused. Your question is not about sorting a list. Pull yourself together.

Answer (score 0):

The lock-free data structures use atomic reads and writes (e.g. [compare-and-swap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap)) to eliminate the need for locks. Naturally, these data structures never blocks.

What you describe is a queue that uses lock-free mechanisms for non-blocking calls, e.g. `remove()` with non-empty queue, while uses lock to block for e.g. `remove()` on empty queue.

As you might realize this is not possible to implement. If, for example, you were to after a pop operation, see if the queue was in fact empty and then proceed to block, by the time you block, the queue might already have one or more items inserted by another thread.

Comment: Yes, I think it is perfect reasonable to expect the thread can block if there is (near) 0 items left in the queue, and obviously same applies when the queue is (near) full. I just don't think there MUST BE any potential blocking operation on the FAST PATH. Or there is indeed some reason that can't be possible? For example, in the Single Producer Single Consumer case, perhaps the producer and the consumer can update their own pointer, and don't affect each other (in the fast path) ?